# Good library/platform for a real-time/parallel HTTP crawler?

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, web-crawler, node.js, eventmachine

I am building a crawler that fetches information in parallel from a number of websites in real-time in response to a request for this information from a client. I need to request specific pages from 10-20 websites, parse their contents for specific snippets of information and return this information to the client as fast as possible. I want to do it asynchronously, so the client gets the first result displayed as soon as it is ready, while the other requests are still pending.

I have a Ruby background, and would therefore prefer to build the solution in a Ruby - however, parallelism and speed is exactly what Ruby is known NOT to excel at. I believe that libraries such as [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) and [Typhoeus](http://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus) can remedy that, but I am also strongly considering [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), because I know javascript quite well and seems to be built for this kind of thing.

Whatever I choose, I also need an efficient way to communicate the results back to the client. I am considering plain AJAX (but that would require polling the server), web sockets (but that would require fallback for older browsers) and specific solutions for persistent client/server communication such as [Cramp](http://github.com/lifo/cramp), [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) and [Pusher](http://www.pusherapp.com/).

Does anyone have any experience and/or recommendations they would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node is definitely capable of handling this type of task - async socket and http communciation is baked in and really pleasant to work with.

Most of my work is j/Ruby and I have found the transition to server-side JavaScript pretty painless - years of web dev mean I know js pretty well and the server development concepts are largely the same regardless of language.

In terms of communication [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is an excellent client and server framework for handling socket communication in node - it supports flash, ajax and websocket channels which means it can be used on just about any modern (and some older) browsers.

Comment: +1 for jruby since it can handle true multi-threaded, though I suppose 1.9 would work as well

Answer (score 0):

If your crawler needs Javascript support, I recommend http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/.
There is a JRuby wrapper available http://celerity.rubyforge.org/

Features (taken from site) include:

- Fast - No time-consuming GUI
  rendering or unessential downloads
- Easy to use - Simple API
- JavaScript support
- Scalable - Java threads lets you run tests in parallel
- Portable - Cross-platform thanks to the JVM
- Unintrusive - No browser window interrupting your workflow (runs in
  background)